# Tuning recommendations for Autovacuum

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, autovacuum

The AUTOVACUUM daemon is made up of multiple processes that reclaim storage by removing obsolete data or tuples from the database. It checks for tables that have a significant number of inserted, updated, or deleted records and vacuums these tables based on the configuration settings

1. You can determine if the table in your database needs vacuuming by running the below query:

   SELECT datname, age(datfrozenxid) FROM pg_database ORDER BY age(datfrozenxid) desc limit 20;
2. While you are connected to your database, running the following query will help to see a list of tables that autovacuum sees as eligible for vacuuming:

   ```
             WITH vbt AS (SELECT setting AS autovacuum_vacuum_threshold FROM 
           pg_settings WHERE name = 'autovacuum_vacuum_threshold')
               , vsf AS (SELECT setting AS autovacuum_vacuum_scale_factor FROM 
           pg_settings WHERE name = 'autovacuum_vacuum_scale_factor')
               , fma AS (SELECT setting AS autovacuum_freeze_max_age FROM 
           pg_settings WHERE name = 'autovacuum_freeze_max_age')
               , sto AS (select opt_oid, split_part(setting, '=', 1) as param, 
           split_part(setting, '=', 2) as value from (select oid opt_oid, 
           unnest(reloptions) setting from pg_class) opt)
           SELECT
               '"'||ns.nspname||'"."'||c.relname||'"' as relation
               , pg_size_pretty(pg_table_size(c.oid)) as table_size
               , age(relfrozenxid) as xid_age
               , coalesce(cfma.value::float, autovacuum_freeze_max_age::float) 
           autovacuum_freeze_max_age
               , (coalesce(cvbt.value::float, autovacuum_vacuum_threshold::float) 
           + coalesce(cvsf.value::float,autovacuum_vacuum_scale_factor::float) * 
           c.reltuples) as autovacuum_vacuum_tuples
               , n_dead_tup as dead_tuples
           FROM pg_class c join pg_namespace ns on ns.oid = c.relnamespace
           join pg_stat_all_tables stat on stat.relid = c.oid
           join vbt on (1=1) join vsf on (1=1) join fma on (1=1)
           left join sto cvbt on cvbt.param = 'autovacuum_vacuum_threshold' and 
           c.oid = cvbt.opt_oid
           left join sto cvsf on cvsf.param = 'autovacuum_vacuum_scale_factor' and 
           c.oid = cvsf.opt_oid
           left join sto cfma on cfma.param = 'autovacuum_freeze_max_age' and 
           c.oid = cfma.opt_oid
           WHERE c.relkind = 'r' and nspname <> 'pg_catalog'
           and (
               age(relfrozenxid) >= coalesce(cfma.value::float, 
           autovacuum_freeze_max_age::float)
               or
               coalesce(cvbt.value::float, autovacuum_vacuum_threshold::float) + 
           coalesce(cvsf.value::float,autovacuum_vacuum_scale_factor::float) * 
           c.reltuples <= n_dead_tup
              -- or 1 = 1
           )
           ORDER BY age(relfrozenxid) DESC LIMIT 50;
   ```
3. Some parameter affects the behavior of autovacuum and running the following query shows the values of some of the parameters that directly affect autovacuum and its behavior:

   ```
           SELECT name, setting, unit, short_desc
           FROM pg_settings
           WHERE name IN (
           'autovacuum_max_workers',
           'autovacuum_analyze_scale_factor',
           'autovacuum_naptime',
           'autovacuum_analyze_threshold',
           'autovacuum_analyze_scale_factor',
           'autovacuum_vacuum_threshold',
           'autovacuum_vacuum_scale_factor',
           'autovacuum_vacuum_threshold',
           'autovacuum_vacuum_cost_delay',
           'autovacuum_vacuum_cost_limit',
           'vacuum_cost_limit',
           'autovacuum_freeze_max_age',
           'maintenance_work_mem',
           'vacuum_freeze_min_age');
   ```

While these all affect autovacuum, some of the most important ones are:

```
            maintenance_mork_mem
            autovacuum_freeze_max_age
            autovacuum_max_workers
            autovacuum_vacuum_cost_delay
            Autovacuum_vacuum_cost_limit
```

Below is the definition/explanation of some of these important options:

Autovacuum_freeze_max_age 
Specifies the maximum age (in transactions) that a table's pg_class.relfrozenxid field can attain before a VACUUM operation is forced to prevent transaction ID wraparound within the table. Note that the system will launch autovacuum processes to prevent wraparound even when autovacuum is otherwise disabled.

autovacuum_max_workers (integer)
This option specifies the maximum number of autovacuum processes that may be running at any one time as the cleanup does not happen in a single autovacuum process. The default is three (3).

autovacuum_vacuum_cost_limit
This option specifies the cost limit value that will be used in automatic VACUUM operations. If -1 is specified (which is the default), the regular vacuum_cost_limit value will be used. Note that the value is distributed proportionally among the running autovacuum workers, if there is more than one, so that the sum of the limits for each worker does not exceed the value of this variable.

autovacuum_vacuum_cost_delay
This option specifies the cost delay value that will be used in automatic VACUUM operations. If -1 is specified, the regular vacuum_cost_delay value will be used. The default value is 20 milliseconds.

autovacuum_vacuum_scale_factor
This option specifies how often autovacuum is triggered. If you want the autovacuum to run more frequently,I recommend using a small value for autovacuum_vacuum_scale_factor (such as 0.02 or 0.01). The smaller the value is for this parameter, the less the number of dead tuples that autovacuum will work on each time. For large tables, this means autovacuum can take less I/O and less time to finish.

Note: For small tables, there may be a concern that autovacuum runs unnecessarily frequently and incurs overhead. If your tables have various sizes or different write patterns, I recommend that you set this parameter with different values at the table level, instead of one value at the database level. For further definition of Autovacuum options, please review this document [2]

[1]Autovacuum Tuning - https://www.2ndquadrant.com/en/blog/autovacuum-tuning-basics/
[2]Further Autovacuum option definition - https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/runtime-config-autovacuum.html#GUC-AUTOVACUUM-MAX-WORKERS

Comment: SO is here to answer your questions. I do not see a question here, please specify one.